# Rails ActiveRecord default values are overridden by default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

DB Scheme

```rb
create_table "user", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "active", default: false
end
```

Model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { where(active: true) } # removing this line and it works
end

u = User.create!(name: "test")
# ^^^^ this creates a User with active: true

u.active? # true (should be false)
```

When I remove `default_scope` it works as expected.

Why is `default_scope` changing my default values.
As far as I know `default_scope` is only used in queries and not in creation?

Comment: I suggest reading [this page in the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html). Quote: _The default_scope is also applied while creating/building a record. It is not applied while updating or deleting a record._ Depending on your needs you might want to use `unscoped` of remove the `default_scope` completely.

Comment: Ok, but it feels totally unnaturally for me, creating each User (or other models) with `User.unscoped.create!` only to have predefined default values in the DB-scheme applied. Which use case needs default_scope in a creation process? I thought this is where `default:` values are for. Also default attribute values ( `attribute :active, default: -> { false }`) are overriden with `default_scope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default_scope` is also applied while creating/building a record. It is not applied while updating or deleting a record.

Ref: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope

If you need a scope for query usage only, consider using the normal scope instead.

Comment: Even `attribute :active, default: -> { false }` are overriden with `default_scope` defined. Sorry, that all makes no sense for me. Is it intentionally to create Users with `User.unscoped.create!` only to have in DB scheme defined default values applied? What about fabricators and fixtures? I really dont get the use case for such a behaviour.

Comment: Yea, `default_scope` is not a "scope" and it's name is misleading. I seldom use it because it's behavior is not observable and always makes everybody confused. For example, `User.all` is not  "all users" if `default_scope` is applied. I prefer using normal scopes, for example: `User.active` to represent "All active users", make code more readable.